# sudo not preserving PS1

Tags: sudo

The configuration below is in my `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults    !visiblepw
Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS EDITOR DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

When I `sudo su` my `PS1` terminal changes to the system default; ignoring my `.bashrc` `PS1` setting. How can I fix this so that the environment variables are not lost when `sudo su`ing?

Weird; it's exporting `EDITOR` but it's not exporting `PS1` for some reason; it's like it's being forcefully overridden; how can I stop this?

When I run `sudo -V` the variables to keep `PS1` is listed; it's not listed in the variables to remove.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `sudo su`. It's an abuse/useless use of `su`. The proper equivalent is `sudo -s`.

If you want to preserve environment variables, you want `sudo -Es`.

---

If you find that `$PS1` is still changing, you likely have a script doing it. You can find out where by doing `sudo -Es $SHELL -x` and reading through the output.

Comment: I've run into issues trying to use `growisofs` where it won't work with anything except `sudo su -`.

Comment: @slm `sudo su -` equivalent would be `sudo -i` (login shell). If you're using SELinux, there are other options for that as well.

Comment: @josten you can see what gets preserved by doing `sudo -E env`. Make sure that `PS1` has even been exported (`export PS1`), as it's not required to be.

Comment: @Patrick - yeah I've tried several of the `sudo` methods and they all result in this w/ `growisofs`. 

... :-( growisofs is being executed under sudo, aborting! See NOTES paragraph in growisofs manual page for further details....

Comment: @slm Wow, that's just stupid in my opinion. It's not the job of destination program to prevent `sudo` from being abused. VI, bash, and any number of other utilities don't prevent themselves from being run under `sudo`. That's what `sudoers` is for.

Comment: @Patrick - I'd always thought so myself too, but in looking at the NOTES section of the man page I now understand why they took this position: http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/linux/DVD+RW/growisofs.1m.html

Comment: @Patrick - excerpt: ...Being executed under sudo(8), growisofs effectively grants sudoers read access to any file in the file system. The situation is intensified by the fact that growisofs parses MKISOFS environment variable in order to determine alternative path to mkisofs executable image. This means that being executed under sudo(8), growisofs effectively grants sudoers right to execute program of their choice with elevated privileges..."

Comment: @slm lets continue discussion in chat.

Comment: @josten So `sudo` is preserving `PS1` just fine. Which is what your question asks.

Comment: @josten I updated my question with how you can track down where `$PS1` is being changed. At this point it's going to be in a bashrc script somewhere.

Comment: @slm - i would be interested to see what file descriptors are open for `growisofs` both before and after an attempt at execing it via `sudo`. As i understand it `sudo` discards all fds not `0<&>&1,2`. I think that if a utility requires more they tend to stall.

Answer (score 6):

A year or two ago, the authors and package maintainers of the Unix system shells agreed that it is generally better to *not* `export PS1` (due to vast syntax differences between the various shells combined with certain “explosive” behaviour of some shells when provided with the prompts of other shells). We all agreed on moving `PS1` initialisation to the interactive shell startup files, that is, `~/.mkshrc`, `~/.kshrc`, `~/.bashrc` etc.

Disclaimer: I'm the mksh developer.

Comment: *The `mksh` dev*? Is it that lonely a road? I do understand the problem you describe - i couldnt use `$(printf \\t)` in a `bash` `$PS1` just yesterday because, as it happens, the common c-escape for `<tab>` is reserved by `bash` for special prompt-expansion.

Comment: @mikeserv just do `tab=$'\t'; PS1='something'$tab'something'; unset tab` then. (Or use mksh ☺) No, it's not lonely, the community/user feedback is amazing. Sure, sometimes I'd wish for a helping hand, but occasionally I do get patches, and very often good inspiration and even delightful bug reports (well written, with reproducer cases and suggestions for one or more ways of fixing it).

Comment: @mikeserv AIUI both AT&T ksh93 and GNU bash are developed by single persons as well (David Korn and Chet Ramey, respectively).

Comment: That's news! Thanks, @mirabilos. It was after I looked over your MirOS website that I deleted my last comment - I wouldn't like to assume you'd have the time - you're a busy guy. I'm curious about `mksh` and `printf` after reading through - but maybe I'll email...

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can explicitly set the `$ENV` source file for a shell upon invocation. For instance, you might have some luck with the following:

```
sudo ENV=/home/$USER/.bashrc su
```

Failing that, you might also try something like:

```
sudo su -c "exec </dev/tty ENV="~/.bashrc" bash -i"
```

Answer (score 1):

`PS1` is probably initialized at shell startup. I.e. the value is indeed preserved by `sudo` but afterwards overwritten by the shell.